# Call static method in static class from asp page

Tags: asp.net, static, static-methods

When I call static method from asp page I got this Compilation Error:

```
CS0103: The name 'Tudo' does not exist in the current context 
Line 10: <script src="<%= Tudo.getFromDefinicao("winJS") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Tudo is a static class which is in App_Code paste, and the namespace is the same of my asp pages.

```
namespace MySite
{
   public static class Tudo
   {
     public static string getFromDefinicao(string key)
     {
        //do some stuff
        return myString;
     }
   }
}
```

I want call getFromDefinicao(...) method from my asp, but asp don't find the class (in this case i'm calling in my MasterPage). If I call the methods inside Tudo.cs from MasterPage.cs I have no problem, and I don't need to declare "using 'namespace';" because they are in the same namespace...

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MySite.MasterPage" %>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="<%= Tudo.getFromDefinicao("winJS") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
.......
```

What I have to do to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

try to add the namespace `MySite`

```
<script src="<%= MySite.Tudo.getFromDefinicao("winJS") %>
```

Comment: I got this error: Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'MySite.Tudo' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e22c2559\92c7e946\assembly\dl3\15b7a136\b0ad4c8e_c9e8cd01\MySite.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\e22c2559\92c7e946\App_Code.-jcciwpl.dll'

Comment: probably you have an ambiguous class method. Try to change the namespace or remove the other method

Answer (score 1):

Solution: add the namespace when calling the method:

`<script src="<%= MyNamespace.MyStaticClass.myMethod()`

If appears this error:

> Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'MySite.Tudo' exists in both 'C:...' and 'c:..'

Remove the class from ASP.NET Folder App_Code to another one.